# generate dyanmic file name and write to some other directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am able to do this in shell command line.

```
filename="/home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing/110001_ABC Traffic_04May2020_header_only.csv"
output_filename=$(basename "$filename")

cat "/home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing/110001_ABC Traffic_04May2020_header_only.csv" > /home/vikrant_singh_rana/enrichment_files/"$output_filename"
```

It was able to read given file from `'/home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing'` and has written file with same name to other dir `'/home/vikrant_singh_rana/enrichment_files'`

When I am doing same thing in shell script. Its not working

```
#!/bin/bash

# Go to where the files are located
filedir=/home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing/*
first='yes'
#reading file from directory
for filename in $filedir; do
        #echo $filename
        output_filename=$(basename "$filename")
        #echo $output_filename

#done
done > /home/vikrant_singh_rana/enrichment_files/"$output_filename"
```

while running this I am getting this error

```
/home/vikrant_singh_rana/enrichment_files/: Is a directory
```

Comment: You're using `"$output_filename"` outside the loop, but it's first set inside the loop. (Think of what you're running as `{ for fileiname in ... do ...; done; } > /home/vikrant_singh_rana/enrichment_files/"$output_filename"` What would the point even be, since the variable changes inside the loop each time, but you're only redirecting once?

Comment: Why do you use `cat` for copying files...?

Comment: that I just did for checking the command.. may be I need to use a cp or move statement inside a loop itself

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/591751

Comment: @HaukeLaging it's a common method to replace file but keep permissions on target

Comment: @alecxs Strange method. How would that be different from using `cp`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging cp will create new inode and would use default permissions (or with -a copy permissions) funfact, even a simply sed -i will reset secontext that's why i use cat > in such case. cat is also good replacement for dd if no options needed ;)

Comment: @alecxs That is not correct. `cp` uses the existing inode. Even `cp -p` does; it just changes the metadata. `sed -i` is something completely different because it creates a temporary file and renames that in the end, i.e. replaces the old inode with the new one.

Comment: @HaukeLaging thx for clarifying, seems i have mixed up things regarding inodes. i just remember i have had problems with cp doesn't work for secontext (even busybox cp with -c flag did not work on debian) so i ended up with cat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use pathname expansion (`*`) incorrectly. And as muru's comment states you mix the use of variables inside and outside the loop.

```
#! /bin/bash

source_dir_path='/home/vikrant_singh_rana/testing'
target_dir_path='/home/vikrant_singh_rana/enrichment_files'
cd "$source_dir_path" || exit 1
for filename in *; do
    target_path="${target_dir_path}/${filename}"
    test -f "$target_path" && { echo "File '${filename}' exists; skipping"; continue; }
    cp -p "$filename" "$target_path"
done
```

Comment: actually I was reading file from dir and was doing something on it and trying to write that new file with same name to other directory

Comment: @vikrantrana Then you just have to exchange the `cp` line against the required command.